# Sort files by Timestamp with the Windows DIR command

Tags: windows, sorting, batch-file, timestamp, dir

I want to sort following files with DIR by their Timestamp, which is defined in the filename - oldest first:
Timestamp = YYYYDDMM

```
NAME_20121410.dat
NAME_20121509.dat
NAME_20121609.dat
```

The result should look like this:

```
NAME_20121509.dat
NAME_20121609.dat
NAME_20121410.dat
```

How do i achieve that with an one-liner?

Comment: @jeb - Actually, I don't think a simple one liner is possible. I believe the OP wants to sort based on the date in the name, not based on the last modified or created timestamp. There may not be a correlation between the date in the name and the file timestamps.

Comment: I think of `dir /O-N`, but I reread the question and see the stupid date format `YYYY DD MM` instead of `YYYY MM DD`. Then it's a bit tricky to solve

Comment: @jeb yes, the date format is indeed stupid. i will ask the suppliers of the file to use a more sort friendly format (YYYYMMDD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the date format is stupid, you need to split first the filenames and sort the rearranged names.
Not a one liner, but it works (inside a batch file).

```
@echo off
(
  for %%A in (*_*.dat) do @(
    call set "name=%%A"
    call set "nameDate=%%name:*_=%%"
    call set "Year=%%nameDate:~0,4%%"
    call set "Day=%%nameDate:~4,2%%"
    call set "Month=%%nameDate:~6,2%%"
    call echo %%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%% %%name%%
  )
) | sort | (
  for /F "tokens=1,*  delims= " %%A in ('more') DO @echo %%B
)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you can use PowerShell, try this:

```
PS II> ls *.dat | sort {$_ -replace '(\d{2})(\d{2})\.*','$2$1'}
```